# Mariabackup flush and delete bin log

Tags: backup, mariadb, binlog

I'm using Mariabackup and I'd like to know if there is an option to allow me to rotate the binary log when running mariabackup. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough it does to a "FLUSH BINARY LOGS" when it detects GTID during the backup and this is under the `--galera-info` flag.

If you think it should be elsewhere or under a different option, please raise a [feature request](https://jira.mariadb.org) under the MDEV project.

ref: [code reference](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/cbabb95915d55ce7004f4b7e103aa1143549d384/extra/mariabackup/backup_mysql.cc#L1447).